# What is currently a good way to develop a Vaadin 8 project with Eclipse?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Yesterday I tried to create a Vaadin project as described under https://vaadin.com/framework/get-started

I did it that way because the current eclipse plugin doesn't support greating Vaadin 8 projects.

Then I imported the project using Eclipse Import->Existing Maven Projects.

THis worked almost fine - only when starting the project using "Debug on Server" the Browser cannot connect to the application, although the application seems to be loaded.

When using `mvn clean install` and deploying the war manually this works.

What is missing there? Is there currently a good way of using Vaadin 8 with Eclipse?

Comment: Apparently the registered web context is  /PROJECTNAME-1.0-SNAPSHOT and not, as eclipse expects it, just /PROJECTNAME

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is more of an eclipse configuration question. 
The context root can be changed using the projects Properties->Web Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would already use Vaadin together with spring-boot. On spring site they do have also a nice initializer tool to create your project: https://start.spring.io/ (Vaadin 8 is already used)

Also very helpful: http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/

The big advantage of using spring for me is the dependency injection, which  simplifies the project setup.